# How to reduce runtime complexity when exchanging data between two collections

Tags: algorithm, java-stream, java-11

There is such a task. There are 2 collections, the **List** type (collections can be of different types), but at the moment the List is accepted as the starting point.

- pom.xml

```xml
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>easy-random-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

There are 2 objects :

- **NodeNewData**
- **Node**

```java
public class Node {

    private String idNode;
    
    private NodePosition nodePosition;
    
    private String nameNode;

//getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class NodePosition {

    private double xPos;
    private double yPos;
    private double zPos;
//getters and setters

}
```

```java
public class NodeNewData {

    private String idNode;

    private NodePosition nodePosition;
```

For each object, there is a collection, which is the input for processing the request.

the **List** collection will consist of **3000** records.

the **List** collection will consist of **10 - 100** records (rarely **1000**).

You need data from List( namely, only **NodePosition** ), update each node in **List**, of course, in accordance with the **idNode** for each node.

As an example, I used 2 nested loops

```
public class CollectionChange {

    private List<Node> nodeList;

    private List<NodeNewData> nodePositionList;

    public CollectionChange(List<Node> nodeList, List<NodeNewData> nodePositionList) {
        this.nodeList = nodeList;
        this.nodePositionList = nodePositionList;
    }

    public void runChangeBetweenCollectionON2(){
        
        nodeList.forEach(nodeTarget -> {

            nodePositionList
                    .stream()
                    .filter(nodeWithNewPosition -> nodeWithNewPosition.getIdNode()
                            .equals(nodeTarget.getIdNode()))
                    .forEach(
                            nodeWithNewPosition -> nodeTarget.setNodePosition(nodeWithNewPosition.getNodePosition())
                    );
        });
    }
    
}
```

- a test circuit

```java
class CollectionChangeTest {

    private static CollectionChange collectionChange;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {

        int countObjects = 3000;
        final List<Node> nodeList = fillList(Node.class, countObjects);

        countObjects = 100;
        final List<NodeNewData> nodePositionList = fillList(NodeNewData.class, countObjects);

        collectionChange = new CollectionChange(nodeList, nodePositionList);
    }

    private static <T> List<T>  fillList (Class<T> clazz, int countObjects){

        EasyRandom generator = new EasyRandom();

        return generator
                .objects(clazz, countObjects)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Test
    void runChangeBetweenCollectionON2() {

        Instant startProcessRequest = Instant.now();

        collectionChange.runChangeBetweenCollectionON2();

        Instant finishProcessRequest = Instant.now();

        long resultTimeOfProcessRequest = Duration
                .between(startProcessRequest,finishProcessRequest)
                .toSeconds();

        outputResult(resultTimeOfProcessRequest);
        
    }

    private void outputResult(long resultTimeOfProcessRequest){
        String messageInfoFirst = "Request processing time";
        String messageInfoSecond = " seconds.";

        final String formatMessageInfo = String.format("%s : %d %s", messageInfoFirst,
                resultTimeOfProcessRequest, messageInfoSecond);

        System.out.println(formatMessageInfo);
    }
}
```

The time complexity of this algorithm (updating data between two collections) is O (n^2), as I assume (due to **2 nested loops**).

I must say that the collections come in the **List** format ( as an implementation , it is worth - **ArrayList**).

Can you suggest optimization algorithms for this task to reduce the complexity of the execution time ?

What is the benefit of filter () in this case, that is, does it affect the complexity of the execution time ?

It was suggested to use the smaller one as the leading collection. Will the complexity of the execution time change ? ( In my opinion-it will be longer)?

How appropriate is the use of parallelsStream() in this case ?

**Update.**

So. I decided to follow the advice and did the following:

1. First, I moved the largest collection to map.
2. Then I started going through the collection, which contains only the nodes that need to be updated.
3. So the runtime complexity would be O(n).

```java
/**
     * O (n)
     */
    public List<Node> runChangeBetweenCollectionON(){

        final Map<String, Node> nodesInMap = convertListToMapWDuplicates(nodeList);

        nodePositionList
                .stream()
                .filter(nodeNewData -> {

                    final String idNode = nodeNewData.getIdNode();
                    final Node node = nodesInMap.get(idNode);

                    if(node != null) return idNode.equals(node.getIdNode());
                    return false;
                })
                .forEach(nodeNewData -> {
                    final Node nodeTarget = nodesInMap.get(nodeNewData.getIdNode());
                    nodeTarget.setNodePosition(nodeNewData.getNodePosition());
                });

        final List<Node> nodeList = nodesInMap
                .values()
                .stream()
                .collect(toList());

        return nodeList;

    }

    public Map<String, Node> convertListToMapWDuplicates(List<Node> list) {

        Map<String, Node> map = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Node::getIdNode, node -> node, (nodeFirst, nodeSecond) -> nodeSecond));
        return map;
    }
```

When passing a collection to map, you need to make sure that there is no duplicate error. If, on the contrary, you want to see that you have duplicates in the collection when processing the stream, then use the method

```java
  public Map<String, Node> convertListToMap(List<Node> list) {

        Map<String, Node> map = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Node::getIdNode, node -> node));
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: several questions asked in this topic-overlap (reveal each other). Therefore, I do not see the point of duplicating this topic in order to divide it into several.

Comment: This question can be answered by only looking at the code of `CollectionChange.runChangeBetweenCollectionON2()`. All the other code and even more the pom.xml are irrelevant to the question. It’s just noise. The answer is, run over one list and store the elements into a `Map` mapping from the id to the element, then run over the second list and look up the elements from the map instead of iterating over the first list. With a `HashMap`, this makes it O(n) overall time complexity. Since you asked about time complexity, `parallelsStream()` is irrelevant as it doesn’t change the time complexity.

Comment: This looks like homework or an exam question

Comment: neither one nor the other. There are many places in the project where nested loops are used. and the question arose, is this correct ? Maybe you can do it faster ?

Comment: You are correct in that such nested loops have O(n²) time complexity that can backfire with larger lists. As said, parallel processing does not change the time complexity, it just divides the time by the fixed number of CPU cores, in the best case. So it’s still O(n²). By only looking at the nested loop, I would come up with `var map = nodePositionList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(n -> n.getIdNode(), n -> n)); nodeList.forEach(target -> { var nodeWNewPos = map.get(target.getIdNode()); if(nodeWNewPos != null) target.setNodePosition(nodeWNewPos.getNodePosition()); });` having O(n).

Comment: @Holger hello. I checked, but here we can get the error: java.lang. IllegalStateException: Duplicate key.  This error occurs when translating the collection to Map

Comment: Also, why not convert the leading collection (3000) to a Map. Since it is larger and then for foreach() we would only need to run through the list that contains the changes, which is much smaller.

Comment: You’re always iterating over both collections, over one to fill the map, over the other looking up the map. You can do it either way, though storing the smaller one into the map saves some of the temporarily required memory. It wasn’t clear from the question that multiple IDs are possible. Since the code suggests that the target has only one `NodePosition` property, you have to define how such cases should be handled.